# For a different proof of the boundedness theorem of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The bounded-ness  theorem of continuous functions i.e. every continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is bounded on the closed bounded real interval $[a,b]$ can be proved by Bolzano -Weirstrass theorem ( as is usually done in text-books) and also by Nested Interval Theorem ( as is done in Apostol) ; since in $\mathbb R$ these two theorems and Cauchy Criterion and Monotone Convergence theorem are all equivalent , my question is can we prove the bounded-ness  theorem by directly using Cauchy Criteria or Monotone Convergence theorem  ?

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

If $f$ is unbounded from above then for each $n\geq1$ the set $A_n:=\{x\in[a,b]\ |\ f(x)\geq n\}$ is nonempty. Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ defined by $x_n:=\inf A_n$.